# void as an argument

Tags: c#, delegates, argument-passing

I'm programming in c#. I need a function which creates a Button, specifies its name and some of its events. I need to pass its name and events as arguments. I have done this:

```
    private void createButton(string name, EventHandler hover, EventHandler click)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Name = name;
        button.Image = Properties.Resources.print_trans;
        button.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(hover);
        button.Click += new System.EventHandler(click);
        button.Visible = false;
        this.Controls.Add(button);
    }
```

In another part of the code I make these calls:

```
    createButton("cmdPrint", this.Hover, this.Print);
    createButton("cmdMark", this.Hover, this.Mark);
```

The calls generate this error: *"The best overloaded method match for createButton(string, System.EventHandler, System.EventHandler)' has some invalid arguments"*.

What type of arguments should **hover** and **click** be?

Edit:

**Jon:**
*Hover* and *Print* are Events:

```
    private void Hover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Proofs.ShowInformation((Control)sender);
    }

    private void Print(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Proofs.Print((Control).sender);
    }
```

The two call lines generate the same error.

**Steve:**
My Events *Print* and *Hover* have the typical Event syntax, but I don't know what type should have *hover* and *click* in *createButton* function.

Edit2:

My problem is solved. I just add this delegate:

```
private delegate void Del(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Change the calls:

```
Del print = this.Imprimir;
Del hover = this.Hover;        
createButton("cmdPrint", this.Hover, this.Print);
createButton("cmdMark", this.Hover, this.Mark);
```

And change the arguments (in *createButton*):

```
private void createButton(string name, Del hover, Del click)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well what are `this.Hover` and `this.Print` meant to be? And *which* of those two lines is causing a problem? It would really help if you'd provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The two EventHandler parameters should be functions that have this signature:

```
void MyFunction(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

If you look up [`EventHandler` on the MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx), you can see the syntax of this delegate described as:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public delegate void EventHandler(
    Object sender,
    EventArgs e
)
```

This tells you the return type and the type of the parameters for that signature.